# How do I properly link JQuery and use .getJSON?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I'm trying to link JQuery and call `.getJSON`, but getting errors with the script tags

> (SyntaxError: Unexpected token <)

Doing console.log just as a call to see what would be printed, because I'm extremely new to Javascript and JQuery...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

$.getJSON('https://www.reddit.com/r/aww', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: The code you posted should work if it's in an `.html` file. The error you got suggests that you tried to put HTML in a `.js` file.

Comment: @Barmar is right, it needs to be `.html`, also, you'll have to surround your code in a script tag too: `<script>$.getJSON(...)</script>`. Alternatively, you could make a separate JS file (we'll call it `custom.js`), and add both the jQuery inclusion and an inclusion to your local script (`<script src='custom.js'></script>`). Also, due to CORS, you won't be able to pull JSON from /r/aww.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is, your code only will work if you put inside a HTML file.

but your error probably is because you don't have the block :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>


 <script>
 $.getJSON('https://www.reddit.com/r/aww', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
   })
 </script>
```

all javascript code nedd be inside it: `<script> your code </script>`

look the complete code here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="hello">
  <p>hello word</p>
</div>   

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below implementation:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/api/info.json", function(data) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(data);
    $("#jsonData").html(str);
  }).fail(function(err) {
    $("#jsonData").html(JSON.stringify(err));
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have placed the entire block above inside `<script></script>` tags, which would generate the `Unexpected token <` error, looking something like this:

```
<script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    $.getJSON('https://www.reddit.com/r/aww', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
</script>
```

Move the `<script>` tag on the inside out of the block like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('https://www.reddit.com/r/aww', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
</script>
```